# Performance implications of Expression.Compile for argument null checks

Tags: c#, performance, linq

We are trying to find a more refactor-friendly way of testing for null arguments in our methods so that instead of writing:

```
if (arg1 == null)
{
    throw new ArgumentNullException("arg1")
}

thing1 = arg1;
```

our developers can do something like

```
thing1 = ArgumentNotNull(() => arg1);
```

Here is the code for ArgumentNotNull in the above example:

```
    public static void ArgumentNotNull<T>(Expression<Func<T>> member)
        where T : class
    {
        var argumentName = ((MemberExpression)member.Body).Member.Name;
        var func = member.Compile();
        var argumentValue = func();

        if (argumentValue == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(argumentName);
        }
    }
```

The one question I have with the way we are doing this is: Is Expression.Compile() prohibitively expensive to do for something as trivial as this check?

I have a feeling that we might see some problems down the road as both the number of arguments and calls to methods increase...

Comment: Why would you do this over a static method that takes and input and checks for null?

Comment: Have you measured it? Yes, I would personally avoid using expression trees for this purpose. I just suck it up and specify the parameter name as another argument: `Preconditions.CheckNotNull(foo, "foo");` using an attribute that R# checks to make sure that the argument matches a parameter name. But I wouldn't do it *just* for performance reasons without checking...

Comment: @DavidHaney Presumably to avoid passing parameter name as string.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Yes, that was the point of this whole method.

Comment: Ahhh, in that case this is smart. I had not considered it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.Compile()` call is very expensive, but can be mitigated by caching the compiled method in something like a static `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` where the key is the type of `member`. This way, your first call would be slow and the rest would be just about as fast as a regular method call, since you'd be reusing your method for future checks on a given type. Downside: possible memory bloat or leak for a lot of different types.